# Swift - tableview load error - the dreaded SIGBART

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Started a Xcode project from scratch.  Selected single view option.  Dropped in a tableview over the view.  Selected 1 cell prototype.  Created a cell identifier "cell."  Added UITableViewDelegate and functions needed to satisfy tableview protocol. The tableview is linked to the view controller. The code has no pre-run errors or warnings. However, I get this error:

> 2016-10-15 07:50:29.622 LawDataNHC[5219:196567] *** Assertion failure
>   in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3599.6/UITableView.m:8035
>   2016-10-15 07:50:29.650 LawDataNHC[5219:196567] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'UITableView (; layer = ;
>   contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 44}>) failed to obtain a
>   cell from its dataSource ()'
>   *** First throw call stack:

The material tableview code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
        return 1       
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int  {
        return 1
    }

    private func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = "test"

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Did you set your view controller as the table view's data source?  Also your code won't use your prototype cell as you are just instantiating a UITableViewCell. You need to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to use the prototype cell

Comment: I did set the view controller as the table views delegate and data source.  dequeReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") solution offered by hagfish below doesn't work either.  This is driving me nuts as in the past (Swift 2) I have made other tables using the exact code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten to name the protocol `UITableViewDataSource` in your `ViewController`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

Also your `cellForRowAt` method shouldn't be private:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

And finally try use the `dequeueReusableCell` method for generating cells instead of creating new ones with `UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")`.

Your `ViewController` class should look like the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  //let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = "test"

    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: Good grief...  I'll keep my day job.   It was the omission of the UITableViewDataSource.  Thanks Mr. Balderrama.  I still have hair on my head.

Comment: :) @P.Festus glad it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code  returning nil tableView cell try with following:
Replace with It:

```
private func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = "test"

    return cell
    }
```

Comment: The table view instance can **never** be `nil` in this method.